# How to associate an avatar a user with cloudinary / Django?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I am trying to configure cloudinary on my Django project.

The current configuration resizes avatars of users and hosts them on cloudinary servers.

I would like to associate the public key of is avatar with the id of the users so that when a user wishes to change his avatar the old one is overwritten by the new one.

I would also like that when a user deletes his account, the associated avatar either deletes cloud servers

I do not know if this idea of associating the public key with the user identifier and a good practice or if there is another way to do it?

Here is what I have naively tried to do for the moment:

forms.py

```py
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
   image = forms.ImageField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.FileInput)
   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ['image']
```

views.py

```py
@login_required
def account_edit(request):
   p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)

   if request.method == "POST":
       if p_form.is_valid():
           p_form.save()
           messages.success(request, _(f"Your image has been successfully uploaded!"))
           return redirect('account_edit')
       else:
           messages.error(request, _(f"Image files only"))
           return redirect('account_edit')
   else:
       p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
```

models.py

```py
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField


class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   image = CloudinaryField("avatar",
       folder = "avatar/",
       public_id = request.user.pk, # NameError: name 'request' is not defined
       notification_url = "https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/register-start/avatar",
       resource_type = "image",
       transformation=[
                       {'width': 150, 'height': 150, 'gravity': "center", 'crop': "thumb"},
                       ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could associate the `public_id` of the image with the primary key of the `User` if you want the user to have only one profile picture at any given time (eg. GitHub), instead of multiple (eg. Facebook).

Otherwise, you could use the randomly generated public_id (which is the default when not passing the `public_id` argument), and tag the image with the relevant `User` primary key.

When the person deletes their account, you need to delete the image in Cloudinary using the [Upload API's `destroy` method](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference?query=destroy&c_query=Destroy%20method#destroy_method):

```
cloudinary.uploader.destroy(public_id, **options)
```